# undefined method `days_in_a_month' for Time:Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I tried several things and I can't seem to find the reason why `Time::days_in_a_month` is not found.

I'm trying to calculate the amount of signups for each day of the year, this is the code:

```rb
require 'date'
require 'time'

class GraphicsController < ApplicationController
    def year_graph(year=2013)
        data=calculate_signups(year)
        gon.data=data
    end
    def calculate_signups(year)
        #binding.pry
        month_days=(1..12).map{|x| Time.days_in_a_month(x,year)}
        total_yeardays=month_days.sum
        year_sum=Array.new
        day_sum={day:0,yearday:0,num:0}
        afee=User.clients.year(year)#.month(month)

        month_days.each_with_index do |mindex,mdays|
            (1..mdays).each do |d|
                day_fees=afee..month(mindex).day(d)
                dia=day_sum.dup
                suma=day_fees.length
                dia[:day]=d
                dia[:num]=suma
                dia[:yearday]=Date.new(year,mindex,d).yday
                year_sum << dia
            end
        end

        year_sum
    end
end
```

If I try it in the debugger `pry`(see `binding.pry` line) there is no problem. And of course no problem either when I try it on the console `rails c --sandbox`. I assume I'm missing something, but I don't know what!

Comment: I think it is `days_in_month`, not `days_in_a_month`.

Comment: OMG, I burned/wasted/threw to trashbin, almost 1h of my life. Now I hate terminal autocompletion.thanks :_

Comment: @LoganSerman I'll accept your answer since you were first.

Comment: You can accept his, it's fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct syntax is without `a`. The correct is

```
Time.days_in_month
```

Comment: indeed, thanks for that. I'll wait to see if Logan answers, else I'll accept yours.

Comment: Ok, I didn't see his answer, but it will be fair, he was first.